# mailxコマンド と SMTPサーバ と MTA について

Tags: mail

メール送信の仕組みが分からないので、最も簡単と思われるmailxコマンドについて調べているのですが、下記の意味が分かりません。

[SMTPサーバのメール送信テストにmailxコマンドを使う](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/using-mailx/)

> メールを送信するときには、mailコマンドの後に送信先のメールアドレスを付与します。この際に使用されるSMTPサーバはlocalhostになります。

例えば、デフォルト状態のCentOS7 で下記コマンドを実行するとき、

```
$ mail hoge@example.com
```

#### SMTPサーバはlocalhost？

・この場合はCentOS7のことですか？
・この状況はメールサーバを立てていることにはならない？
・メール送信サーバーとして外部のメールサーバーに提示するホスト名とは異なる？

#### MTAはSendmail ですか？

[CentOS7 に Postfix をインストールする](https://www.saintsouth.net/blog/how-to-install-postfix-on-centos7/)

> CentOS7 のデフォルトのメール送信サーバー (MTA) は Sendmail

日本語に直すと下記のような感じですか？
・localhostであるSMTPサーバから、SMTP認証なしに、SMTPプロトコルで、「Sendmail」MTAを使用して、example.comを管理しているSMTPサーバへメールを送信する

Comment: 質問は、「mailxコマンド」についてですか、それとも「mailコマンド」についてですか？　質問の文章の中に二つの異なるコマンドが混在しているので、何についての質問なのか判りません。

Comment: @Fumu7 質問本文のリンク先でも言及されていますが、CnetOS7で`mail`コマンドは`mailx`へのシンボリックリンクとして提供されています。

Comment: @re9 質問内容を明確にしましょう。1つ目のリンク先では「メール送信テスト」を目的に`mailx`コマンドを使用しています。質問も同じ様にご自身が管理するサーバからのメール送信をテストするのが目的なのか、それとも「メール送信の仕組みそのもの」を理解するのが目的なのかがはっきりしない印象です。タイトルも単語を並べただけなのでやや不親切です。

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 の `mail`(1) あるいは `mailx`(1) (実体は同じなので同じ内容) に記載されているように、デフォルトは `Normally, mailx invokes sendmail(8) directly to transfer messages.` です。Postfix (postfix パッケージ) がインストールされているなら `sendmail`(8) は Postfix のそれなので、その後どのような配送経路になるかは Postfix の設定次第です。

Answer (score 0):

最初の質問ですが、localhost は 127.0.0.1 を指すホスト名です。
127.0.0.1 はループバックアドレスという特殊なIPアドレスでコンピュータ自身をさします。

2つ目の質問の方ですが、MTA=Postfix=STMPサーバー です。
Centos7のデフォルトのMTAはPostfixです。Sendmailも選べますが非推奨です。
※Sendmailのことは忘れていいと思います。

mailx でメール送信する場合は、mailx は localhost上の Postfix(tcp/25=SMTP) に接続して メール送信の要求を行います。

次に postfix は宛先メールアドレスの SMTPサーバーに接続します。 `myhostname = smtp.example.com` と設定した場合は、宛先のSMTPに対して、postfix が smtp.example.com であると名乗ります。

※SMTPプロトコルでは最初にサーバ名を名乗る事になってます。